# Magento custom block rendered twice

Tags: magento-2.1, blocks, frontend, order-success-page

I create a custom checkout block for checkout success page, but unfortunately the data printed twice, First in the right div inside body, and the other printed after the footer, here is the `checkout_onepage_success.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="order.success.additional.info">
        <block class="Namespace\Module\Block\Success"
               name="namespace.order.success"
               template="Namespace_Module::order/success.phtml"
               after="-">
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Comment: have you define block inside footer order.success.additional.info at any place?

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya nope

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite success block as below

create **di.xml** file at **Namespace\Module\etc\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>    
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success" type="Namespace\Module\Block\Success" />
</config>
```

Create your block file **Success.php** at **Namespace\Module\Block\Success.php**

Add below code to it.

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Module\Block;

class Success extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success
{
    /**
     * add your code here
     */

}
?>
```

Now add layout file **checkout_onepage_success.xml** at **Namespace\Module\view\frontend\layout\checkout_onepage_success.xml**

add below code to it

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.success">
       <action method='setTemplate'>
          <argument name='template' xsi:type='string'>Namespace_Module::order/success.phtml</argument>
       </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are encountering is a bug in Magento 2: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4999